# 7 Essential Questions - FAQ Entries

Tags: discussion, 7-questions, faq-proposed

As part of "The 7 Essential Meta Questions of Every Beta" this question is intended to solicit ideas and commentary for site-specific FAQ entries.

Anyone is welcome to suggest entries and discuss proposals, and votes should be used to show agreement or disagreement with a proposal.

**Remember that votes on Politics meta do not have any effect on your site rep, so don't be afraid to downvote!**

Answer (score 6):

### Promoting Balance

I think a major potential issue for this site is going to be bias - in fact, quickly after opening in private beta form somewhat ranting questions pushing towards a bias were posted.

As such, I think we need to make it clear that as well as discouraging opinionated questions and answers, we try to keep them fairly balanced and discourage bias wherever possible.

We've made a great start to this, let's keep it going by making it official.

Comment: It is always better for a question to be stated in a neutral manner. So, "What are the advantages and disadvantages of first past the post?" rather than "First past the post sucks. Is there *any* reason at all to consider using it?"